# Multiple threads and a Boolean register

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, boolean

My question is a pretty simple one; can two different threads set a Boolean to either true or false at the EXACT same instant? If not, why not?

If not what happens when two threads simultaneously reach the code were they set the Boolean to some value, does the hardware arbitrarily make one wait a split moment?

Alternatively if they can then how is the final value determined?

And whether it be yes or no, is it true for all types of variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exact same moment? I suspect you could get picky enough that there's no such thing unless you specify the inertial frame of reference and so on...

If you have a single core, definitely not. It has to run multiple threads by time slicing.

If you have multiple cores in a processor with a single data and address bus, then still no. There is no way that two processes can write to the memory at the same time. The processor has to talk to the memory in a particular way, depending on the type of memory etc. - but basically you have to set up an address, then do a read or write cycle to transfer the data - and you can't have two processes doing that. The memory management hardware will make one of them wait.

If you have two processors, with shared memory, then... still no, if whoever designed the system was in his right mind at the time.

But from a programming point of view, they can be close enough that they might as well be simultaneous; use a critical section, or mutex, or whatever and make one of the threads back off a bit while the other reads, modifies, writes.

But if you have a variable that is larger than your machine's word size (which in this day and age probably means > 64 bits) or an array variable or suchlike, then yes - you could have two threads working on different words in the variable at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation-dependent. It's architecture-dependent. It's processor load-dependent, process scheduling-dependent, dependent on pretty much everything short of the phase of the moon (and I wouldn't put money on the last one).

The short answer is, one of the threads will get its way in the long term. In the short term, they are likely to have inconsistent views of what the actual value of the boolean is, and those views will change after a thoroughly indeterminate (and probably inconsistent) period of time.

The hardware doesn't make one thread wait, because the hardware doesn't automatically know that they're both trying to write to the same memory location at the same time. In the long term it will probably notice this, but at that point it's too late to do anything clever about it. The thread that gets its way with the boolean will be the one whose processor cache happens to write back the cache line *second*. After all, your processor cores don't each have a direct line to your RAM chips. They have to go through your memory controller, and you only have one of those.

As for whether it's true for all variables..... mmmmmostly. If the variable fits in word of memory, definitely for all modern computer architectures. If it fits into one cache line, then probably. But there's also a possibility, particularly for larger structures, that half of the variable will come from one thread, and half from the other. And if the threads are *updating* the memory (incrementing it by one, say) as opposed to solely *writing* to it (setting it to their thread IDs, say), then the likelihood that both threads will succeed in accomplishing what it was they set out to accomplish diminishes further.

The answer to this minefield of bug opportunities, BTW, is (in order of practicality versus performance) (a) the use of synchronization primitives like mutexes, (b) the use of atomic operations, and (c) an understanding of the threaded memory model which is in play.